# Debugging of CygWin gcc compiled programs by Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, gcc

Is it possible to debug Windows hosted programs compiled by cygwin gcc by using Visual Studio debugger?

Answer (score 3):

Not really - the GCC and MS compiler debug information formats are different. You should be able to use the MS debugger in machine code mode, but you won't see all the class & variable names etc.

If you are wanting to use the MS debugger because you find gdb too intimidating, you can get quite  a nice GUI front end for it at http://sourceware.org/insight.

Answer (score 1):

cygwin has gdb - use that.